# How to update view from Angular factory

Tags: angularjs

I might be going about this completely wrong, so I'm open to any suggestions.  Thank you!

A jQuery event listener passes an element into my quickComposeFactory when clicked (This is the only part I can't change right now :( ).

[Here is plunker demonstration.](http://plnkr.co/edit/QG4Xvi6QX9PDaSW4npZ8?p=preview)

```
$('#results').on('click', '.toggleQuickCompose', function() {
    quickComposeFactory.init($(this).parents('.isotope-item'));
});
```

My Angular factory evaluates the elem and populates my dynamicContent object that my controller should be able to see in the $scope.

```
app.factory('quickComposeFactory', function() {

    var dynamicContent = {};

    return {

        getDynamicContent : dynamicContent,

        init: function(elem) {
            } else if (elem.attr('phone')){
                dynamicContent.phone = elem.attr('phone');
                $("#QuickComposePhone").modal("show");
            } else {
                $("#QuickComposeFail").modal("show");
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Since I'm importing my factory into a controller I thought data binding would work like it always does.  Problem is, $scope.dynamicContent is never updated for some reason?

```
htsApp.controller('quickComposeController', ['$scope', 'quickComposeFactory', function($scope, quickComposeFactory){

    $scope.dynamicContent = quickComposeFactory.getDynamicContent;

}]);
```

Thus my bootstrap modal does not update.  Help?

```
<div ng-controller="quickComposeController" class="modal hide fade" data-backdrop="false">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Call or Text</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <div>Seller did not include an email.  Please contact:</div>
        <h4>{{dynamicContent.phone}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're relying on jquery's $(id).on('click',fn) to update your UI, you'll need to wrap your update code in an $apply.  Ie. $scope.$apply(function(){...}). This is necessary to trigger a $digest cycle. However, I think if you used an angular approach rather than a jquery approach you'll find it's a lot simpler

Comment: @pixelbits, can you elaborate on what you mean by wrapping my "update code"?

Comment: There's not enough information for me to answer. Maybe post a fiddle?

Comment: @pixelbits, Plunker is here.  http://plnkr.co/edit/QG4Xvi6QX9PDaSW4npZ8?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GVNH2jNUAt4adalHnNMf?p=preview)

Two things that needed to be fixed:

1. If your service is storing a reference to a model, and that model is bound to scope, then you should use angular.copy to preserve the reference:

   ```
   init: function(qcObj) {
     if (qcObj.phone) {
       alert(qcObj.phone);
       angular.copy(qcObj, newQuickCompose)
     }
   }
   ```
2. Since you are handling a jQuery click event, you need to call $apply to trigger a digest cycle:

   ```
   function getPhoneFromElem() {
     $scope.$apply(function()  {
         $scope.dynamicContent = {
            phone: 1234567
         }
         quickComposeFactory.init($scope.dynamicContent);

     });
   }
   ```